# Structuring a View Model Using RxSwift

Tags: swift, mvvm, viewmodel, rx-swift

My view models are fundamentally flawed because those that use a driver will complete when an error is returned and resubscribing cannot be automated.

An example is my `PickerViewModel`, the interface of which is:

```
//  MARK: Picker View Modelling
/**
Configures a picker view.
 */
public protocol PickerViewModelling {
    /// The titles of the items to be displayed in the picker view.
    var titles: Driver<[String]> { get }
    /// The currently selected item.
    var selectedItem: Driver<String?> { get }
    /**
    Allows for the fetching of the specific item at the given index.
    - Parameter index:  The index at which the desired item can be found.
    - Returns:  The item at the given index. `nil` if the index is invalid.
    */
    func item(atIndex index: Int) -> String?
    /**
    To be called when the user selects an item.
    - Parameter index:  The index of the selected item.
     */
    func selectItem(at index: Int)
}
```

An example of the `Driver` issue can be found within my `CountryPickerViewModel`:

```
    init(client: APIClient, location: LocationService) {
        selectedItem = selectedItemVariable.asDriver().map { $0?.name }
        let isLoadingVariable = Variable(false)
        let countryFetch = location.user
            .startWith(nil)
            .do(onNext: { _ in isLoadingVariable.value = true })
            .flatMap { coordinate -> Observable<ItemsResponse<Country>> in
                let url = try client.url(for: RootFetchEndpoint.countries(coordinate))
                return Country.fetch(with: url, apiClient: client)
            }
            .do(onNext: { _ in isLoadingVariable.value = false },
                onError: { _ in isLoadingVariable.value = false })
        isEmpty = countryFetch.catchError { _ in countryFetch }.map { $0.items.count == 0 }.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: true)
        isLoading = isLoadingVariable.asDriver()
        titles = countryFetch
            .map { [weak self] response -> [String] in
                guard let `self` = self else { return [] }
                self.countries = response.items
                return response.items.map { $0.name }
            }
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])

    }
}
```

The `titles` drive the `UIPickerView`, but when the `countryFetch` fails with an error, the subscription completes and the fetch cannot be retried manually.

If I attempt to `catchError`, it is unclear what observable I could return which could be retried later when the user has restored their internet connection.

Any `justReturn` error handling (`asDriver(onErrorJustReturn:)`, `catchError(justReturn:)`) will obviously complete as soon as they return a value, and are useless for this issue.

I need to be able to attempt the fetch, fail, and then display a **Retry** button which will call `refresh()` on the view model and try again. How do I keep the subscription open?

If the answer requires a restructure of my view model because what I am trying to do is not possible or clean, I would be willing to hear the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding ViewModel structuring when using RxSwift, during intensive work on a quite big project I've figured out 2 rules that help keeping solution scalable and maintainable:

1. Avoid any UI-related code in your viewModel. It includes RxCocoa extensions and drivers. ViewModel should focus specifically on business logic. Drivers are meant to be used to drive UI, so leave them for ViewControllers :)
2. Try to avoid Variables and Subjects if possible. AKA try to make everything "flowing". Function into function, into function and so on and, eventually, in UI. Of course, sometimes you need to convert non-rx events into rx ones (like user input) - for such situations subjects are OK. But be afraid of subjects overuse - otherwise your project will become hard to maintain and scale in no time.

Regarding your particular problem. So it is always a bit tricky when you want retry functionality. [Here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/729) is a good discussion with RxSwift author on this topic.

**First way**. In your example, you setup your observables on `init`, I also like to do so. In this case, you need to accept the fact that you DO NOT expect a sequence that can fail because of error. You DO expect sequence that can emit either result-with-titles or result-with-error. For this, in RxSwift we have `.materialize()` combinator.

In ViewModel:

```
// in init
titles = _reloadTitlesSubject.asObservable() // _reloadTitlesSubject is a BehaviorSubject<Void>
    .flatMap { _ in 
        return countryFetch
            .map { [weak self] response -> [String] in
                guard let `self` = self else { return [] }
                self.countries = response.items
                return response.items.map { $0.name }
            }
            .materialize() // it IS important to be inside flatMap
    }

// outside init

func reloadTitles() {
    _reloadTitlesSubject.onNext(())
}
```

In ViewController:

```
viewModel.titles
    .asDriver(onErrorDriveWith: .empty())
    .drive(onNext: [weak self] { titlesEvent in
        if let titles = titlesEvent.element {
            // update UI with 
        }
        else if let error = titlesEvent.error {
            // handle error
        }
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)

retryButton.rx.tap.asDriver()
    .drive(onNext: { [weak self] in
        self?.viewModel.reloadTitles()
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

**Second way** is basically what CloackedEddy suggests in his answer. But can be simplified even more to avoid Variables. In this approach you should NOT setup your observable sequence in viewModel's `init`, but rather return it anew each time:

```
// in ViewController
yourButton.rx.tap.asDriver()
    .startWith(())
    .flatMap { [weak self] _ in
        guard let `self` = self else { return .empty() }
        return self.viewModel.fetchRequest()
            .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { error -> Driver<[String]> in
                // Handle error.
                return .empty()
            })
    }
    .drive(onNext: { [weak self] in 
        // update UI
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: I appreciate this different way of thinking about the problem. However, if `Driver` should not be used in a view model (with the intention of driving views) then what is it's purpose? Also, your second example would break because the button tap would cause a fetch, which would complete, and then the tap observable would no longer exist and the button would do nothing. In my year and a half using RxSwift I've never touched `materialize` and will have to look into it.

Comment: Regarding `Driver` in ViewModel, there are 2 things that worth considering: 1) usually, you want to do some UI work if error happens. Keeping `.asDriver` cast in the view model will make it harder, because you would need other means of propagating error to view controller. 2) in some cases, you want to subscribe to the same sequence but react differently on error.
Regarding second example, your are not correct. `.flatMap` preserves outer sequence lifecycle. Try it and you'll see :)

Comment: I have tried it and I know from experience that I have had to observe the button in it's own function (`configureButton(with:)`) and resubscribe to the button recursively within the `onError:` callback.

Comment: The whole point of Driver is for this type of scenario.  

1. The viewModel is supposed to prep data for display in the view which always needs to be done on the main thread
2. A Driver cannot have an error which forces the handling of any errors into the ViewModel which is what should be happening
3. Drivers inherently have a shareReplay(1) while connected so the same value cna be bound to multiple points int he UI without having to do anything special.

You absolutely should be using a driver for the properties your VM exposes.

Answer (score 0):

I would shift some responsibilities to the view controller.

One approach would be to have the view model produce an Observable which as a side effect updates the view model properties. In the following code example, the view controller remains in charge of the view bindings, as well as triggering the refresh in `viewDidLoad()` and via a button tap.

```swift
class ViewModel {

    let results: Variable<[String]> = Variable([])
    let lastFetchError: Variable<Error?> = Variable(nil)

    func fetchRequest() -> Observable<[String]> {
        return yourNetworkRequest
            .do(onNext: { self.results.value = $0 },
                onError: { self.lastFetchError.value = $0 })
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let viewModel = ViewModel()
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        viewModel.results
            .asDriver()
            .drive(onNext: { yourLabel.text = $0 /* .reduce(...) */ })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag) 

        viewModel.lastFetchError
            .asDriver()
            .drive(onNext: { yourButton.isHidden = $0 == nil })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag) 

        yourButton.rx.tap
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in 
               self?.refresh()
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag) 

        // initial attempt
        refresh()
    }

    func refresh() { 
        // trigger the request
        viewModel.fetchRequest()
            .subscribe()
            .disposed(by: disposeBag) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers are good, but i want to mentioned about [`CleanArchitectureRxSwift`](https://github.com/sergdort/CleanArchitectureRxSwift). This framework really help me to find the way how rx can be applied to my code. The part about "backend" mobile programming (request, parsers, etc) can be omitted, but work with viewModel/viewController has really interesting things.